# Filtering and Ordering

Tags: channel-entries, custom-fields, filter

I'm working on a site that's going to list events. These events will have the following data:

- Title
- Type
- Date
- Location

I'd like to give the user the ability to filter by any one (or combination) of these fields.

I'd also like to give the user the ability to order the remaining results by any one of these fields.

Any thoughts on a good solution to do this? I'm thinking there must be a good plugin that does this?

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Remember you can always use Dynamic Parameters to sort data on the fly - https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/dynamic_parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Potentially look at implementing your Events using Low Events (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events). The template tags allow to set date parameters as well as order_by and sort parameters (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/tags) that should allow you to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question I realised that this is more of a front-end question as opposed to a back-end one. Therefore rather than looking for an expression engine add-on, I can simply output all the entries and then allow a jQuery plugin to take care of the rest.

Having looked around, https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/ seems to be a really good option, offering filtering and sorting with nice animations to make things look great.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the Solspace Supersearch add-on to accomplish this.  We chose not to do ajax/animated filtering, but to filter based on page/url.  Let me know if you need more details.